# ggplot2 xlim function

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to zoom into the boxplot with out loosing values. For ex: my y-axis has 1 to 1000 values. I am using `xlim=c(0,100)` to zoom in. But I am loosing all the values more than 100 and it is effecting my box plot distribution. Is it possible to keep the same boxplot after zooming ?

This is the command I am using

```
qplot(type, count, fill=atin, data=a, geom="boxplot", ylim=c(0,100))
```

Comment: Nevermind. I found the answer. + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(5, 7.5)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 0.5))  # Ticks from 0-10, every .5